# using a variable in glsl

Tags: c++, opengl

so Ive started a few days ago to learn opengl, Through the superbible seventh edition.

just to note: I didn't use their pre-made library with glfw, Or any other kind of a wrapper to opengl.I just manually loaded every function that was needed, and used win32 api to create a basic gameLoop.

Anyway , So far Ive only been able to write a simple program which is made of a very simple vertex shader and a fragment shader, Trying to display a triangle.it worked. but when I tried adding a variable to the vertex shader , in order to get input and move the triangle a bit using somekind of offset, It just seemed to disappear out of the render. I don't know what went wrong, I went through the code couple of times and nothing seemed to be wrong.the declaration of the variable seemed to be ok after I have cutten down a certain part of the code.

this is my vertex shader:

```
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 offset;
void main(void)
{
   const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](vec4(0.25, -0.25,0.5,1.0), vec4(-0.25,-0.25,0.5,1.0), vec4(0.25,0.25,0.5,1.0));
   gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID] + offset;
}
```

Anyway, The certain line of code which actualy made the whole program go wrong is the part when I'm adding the offset. I commented the part of the "+ offset" and it all got fine, But yet. I'ts not what I wanted. I want to add this variable and actualy see that the triangle's position is changing. Yet, It doesn't happen from an unknown reason. I made sure that I compiled the shaders right, That I linked them with the program. Everything looks fine.

here is my fragment shader(just in case something is wrong here):

```
#version 450 core

out vec4 color;
void main(void)
{
    color = vec4(0.0,0.8,1.0,1.0);
}
```

I tried many things, Yet nothing have solved my weird problem.
If anyone is interested in the full source code,ill just post a link here:
[source code](http://pastebin.com/p5YMf57s)

I noticed that the code of the shader itself is corrupted a bit because pastebin ruins it.thats why I posted here the shaders themselves.

I hope someone will have a bit of time to go over my code and try to figure it out.my code is well organized and shouldn't be hard to Understand how it works.

Ill appreciate anyone who tries to help.

edit: I solved it yes!!!!!
anyway, The problem was an AMD known driver bug apparently.
I just had to change location to any other location than 0,changed to 1,and it worked.
its a very strange problem, But I'm glad that Ive solved it.

I saw the solution right here, If anyone is stuck with it too, This thread would be helpful:

[solution](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/185728-glVertexAttrib4fv-not-working)

Comment: Forgot to note: youl need the "gllext.h" file and the "wglext.h" file to compile it.you can get them at the opengl website.

Comment: ok so I solved the problem:

Comment: Are you using a core profile context? Location 0 has a special meaning in the compatibility profile.